# I am learning Python and trying to understand writing to a CSV. I need it to be in a header / row set up and keep getting a float error

Tags: python

```
import csv

FILENAME = "trip.csv"

def save_data(miles, gallons, mpg):
    header = ["Distance", "Gallons", "MPG"]
    data = [miles, gallons, mpg]
    with open(FILENAME, 'w', newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(header)
    with open(FILENAME, 'a', newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(data)

def display_title():
    print("The Miles Per Gallon program.\n")


def calculate_totals(miles, gallons, cost):
    mpg = miles / gallons
    cost_per_mile = miles / cost
    total_fuel_cost = gallons * cost
    display_data(mpg, cost_per_mile, total_fuel_cost, gallons, miles)

def display_data(mpg, cost_per_mile, total_fuel_cost, gallons, miles):
    print()
    print(f"MPG on this trip is {mpg} gallons.")
    print(f"Cost per mile was ", cost_per_mile)
    print(f"Total fuel spent was ", total_fuel_cost)
    print()
    save_data(miles, gallons, mpg)

def main():
    display_title()
    
    choice = "y"
    while choice.lower() == "y":
        miles = float(input("Enter miles driven: "))
        gallons = float(input("Enter gallons used: "))
        cost = float(input("Enter cost per gallon: "))
        calculate_totals(miles, gallons, cost)
        choice = input("Do you wish to enter a new entry: y/n ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

I was trying to get an output into a CSV that had Distance, Gallons and MPG as a header with the rows underneath keeping user input data. I finally figured out how to make the header but now I am getting a float error and nothing I try seems to get rid of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Timothy, welcome to StackOverflow. Please always provide error messages as formatted text. Please provide the *full error message including the stack trace*. Your output looks like it is from a debugger session in some IDE? Also, can you please provide a [mcve]. Note, your program depends on user inputs, but that really has nothing to do with the question. So create a [mcve] that just hard codes the data.

Comment: As an aside, there is no need to open the file twice

Comment: Anyway, you are using `writer.writerows(data)`,  but `data` seems to just be a single row,  it is expecting an iterable of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `writerows` on the second call, which expects an *iterable of iterables* of values, whereas you're only passing it an *iterable* of values.  There's two ways to fix it:

1. Use `writerow`:

```
writer.writerow(data)
```

2. Actually pass in an iterable of iterables, most easily by creating another list:

```
writer.writerows([data,])
```